# Returning the most recent entry in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My workbook has two sheets, we will call them Summery and Events.

In  my Summery sheet, it looks like this

| Name | Last Event |
| --- | --- |
| Name 1 | Event 3 |
| Name 2 | Event 15 |

In my Events sheet it looks like this

| Name | Event | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name 1 | Event 1 | 4/01/2022 |
| Name 1 | Event 2 | 4/01/2022 |
| Name 1 | Event 3 | 4/02/2022 |
| Name 1 | Event 4 | 4/02/2022 |
| Name 2 | Event 1 | 4/03/2022 |
| Name 2 | Event 5 | 4/03/2022 |
| Name 2 | Event 10 | 4/04/2022 |
| Name 2 | Event 11 | 4/10/2022 |
| Name 2 | Event 15 | 4/29/2022 |
| Name 2 | Event 16 | 4/29/2022 |

On the Summery sheet I am using a `FILTER` to return the name, event, and date from the Events sheet on the condition that the name is equal to it's counterpart in row A. And then I use a `SORT` to order the names events and date by the date descending to get the row with the most recent date. Then I get an `INDEX` of the topmost row and return the second column... the problem is. Some events will occur on the same day so I won't get the most recent event. I will get the first event on the most recent day.

My formula on the summery sheet in B2 looks something like this.

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER(Events!A2:C, Events!A2:A = A2),3,FALSE),1,2)
```

How would I go about returning the most recent event? I've tried this.

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER({Events!A2:C, ROW(Events!A2:A)}, Events!A2:A = A2),3,FALSE,4,FALSE),1,2)
```

And it works fine in google sheets. But it doesn't work in Excel.
How would I get this solution in excel

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the last entry with the desired name:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(B2:B11,A2:A11=F1),COUNTIF(A:A,F1))
```

[image]

---

If indeed dates are always in order one could use:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:A11=F1),B2:B11)
```

Or the ms365's equivalent:

```
=XLOOKUP(F1,A2:A11,B2:B11,,,-1)
```

Comment: Close, but we are still getting Event 3 when the most recent event is Event 4 for Name 1. This is not the correct answer.

Comment: So you are relying on order in the list?  The bottom is the most recent?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Then just pull the last one in the list.  See edit

Comment: What about if there were blank rows above? How would I compensate for that?

Comment: not sure what you mean.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. Sorry

Comment: @JvdV yes.  I got anchored with the OP's use of Filter.  Go ahead and answer with that.

Comment: Edited in to keep info in one place since this answer is accepted and appreciated =)